# Any suggestions for effectively testing AJAX enabled web pages using MSVS Tester Edition Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, ajax, testing

It seems like MS really left a massive gaping hole in their automated testing tools in Visual Studio for web pages with AJAX components and I have been hard pressed to find any commentary or third party add-ons that remedy the problem. Anyone have any advice on automating web tests in MSVS for AJAX pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually gave up trying, and just stuck with WATIR

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but you can try this:

https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit

EDIT:Sorry I reread your Q and realized you meant specific to VS. I don't know if you are familiar with Script#, but I had read some talk a little while back that someone was building a testing framework to use with that, and Script# can be used with MSAjax. Might be worth some investigation.

http://scriptsharp.com/